# Event tries to change a TextView that should have been destroyed, after press phone Back Button and access activity again (RxJava)

Tags: android, android-layout, rx-java, android-lifecycle, rx-java2

Yesterday I created a question about a View that was not correctly populated when it was called from a Flowable event. After debugging and doing some tests I decided to delete that question and create a cleaner one, trying to explain better what is happening.

I have a `SearchActivity` with a button that starts the `DetailActivity`:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_click)
public void onButtonClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        // pass beerId param...
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

In `DetailActivity` `onCreate` method I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    txtName = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txtName.setText("TestFromOnCreate");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: text: "+txtName.getText());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: parent: "+txtName.getParent());
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: object: "+txtName);

     // get beerid param
    detailPresenter.load(beerid);
}
```

`DetailActivity` is the 'View' from 'MVP' perspective. So I have a callback method:

```
@Override
    public void showBeer(Beer beer) {
        txtName.setText("TestFromShowBeer");
        Log.d(TAG, "showBeer: text: "+txtName.getText());
        Log.d(TAG, "showBeer: parent: "+txtName.getParent());
        Log.d(TAG, "showBeer: object: "+txtName);
    }
```

in my Presenter, I have the load method:

```
@Override
public void load(String beerId) {
    subscription = interactor
            .load(beerId)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.computation())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
            .subscribe(next -> {
                view.showBeer(next.getData());
            }, error -> {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }, () -> {
                System.out.println("onComplete ");
            });
}

@Override //this method is in presenter and is called in the view's onPause.
public void onDestroy() {
    if (subscription != null && !subscription.isDisposed()){
        subscription.dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, in subscribe I call the method `showBeer` from view.

My presenter call a method from Interactor class:

```
@Override
public Flowable<LocalType<Beer>> load(String beerId) {
    Flowable<LocalType<Beer>> localFlowable = local.load(beerId);
```

And interactor class call a method from `local` where the `Flowable` is created:

```
        @Override
        public Flowable<LocalType<Beer>> load(String id) {
            return Flowable.create(e -> {
                DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child("beers").child(id);



            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    e.onNext(new LocalType<>(dataSnapshot.getValue(Beer.class)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    e.onError(new Throwable(databaseError.getMessage()));
                    ref.removeEventListener(this);
                }
            };
            ref.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
            e.setCancellable(() -> ref.removeEventListener(valueEventListener));
        }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    }
```

When I run the program it opens the `SearchActivity`. I click the button and it goes to `DetailActivity`, changing the `TextView` to "TestFromOnCreate", moments later, the callback method is called and it changes the `TextView` to "TestFromShowBeer": the log printed from execution is:

```
onCreate: text: TestFromOnCreate
onCreate: parent: android.widget.LinearLayout{e4f92fe V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
onCreate: object: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{51f2a5f V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800f0 app:id/txt_name}
showBeer: text: TestFromShowBeer
showBeer: parent: android.widget.LinearLayout{e4f92fe V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1848}
showBeer: object: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{51f2a5f V.ED..... ......ID 24,24-1080,121 #7f0800f0 app:id/txt_name}
```

This is exactly the expected behavior.

The problem happens when I press the back button on the phone and click again on the button. After passing the onCreate method, `TextView` value is setted to: "TestFromOnCreate" but this text doesn't change when the showBeer method is called. The generated log is:

```
onCreate: text: TestFromOnCreate
onCreate: parent: android.widget.LinearLayout{68a8374 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
onCreate: object: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{cbf809d V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800f0 app:id/txt_name}
showBeer: text: TestFromShowBeer
showBeer: parent: android.widget.LinearLayout{b967084 V.E...... .......D 0,0-1080,1848}
showBeer: object: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{f6e506d V.ED..... ......ID 24,24-1080,130 #7f0800f0 app:id/txt_name}
```

As you can see, new LinearLayout and TextView is created (id: cbf809d) but showBeer method modifies the original TextView (f6e506d), which should have been destroyed. I cannot realize why this is happening, but this bug is driving me crazy.

-- EDIT

I made a test making `local.load()` return static data with just(), but the problem still happens:

```
@Override
            public Flowable<LocalType<Beer>> load(String id) {
                return Flowable.just(new LocalType<>(new Beer("heineken")));
}
```

--- EDIT

I found the problem, actually it was a mistake with dagger injection and not with rxJava. I was injecting the view into presenter, I think I made a mistake regarding the scopes:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
        DatabaseModule.class

})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    SearchSubComponent plus (SearchModule searchModule);
    DetailSubComponent plus (DetailModule detailModule);
}




@Module
public class DetailModule {

    DetailView detailView;

    public DetailModule(DetailView detailView) {
        this.detailView = detailView;
    }

    @DetailScope
    @Provides
    public DetailView detailView(){
        return detailView;
    }

    @DetailScope
    @Provides
    DetailPresenter detailPresenter(DefaultDetailPresenter defaultDetailPresenter) {
        return defaultDetailPresenter;
    }

    @DetailScope
    @Provides
    LoadBeerInteractor detailInteractor(DefaultLoadBeerInteractor defaultDetailInteractor) {
        return defaultDetailInteractor;
    }

}




@Inject
public DefaultDetailPresenter(DetailView detailView, LoadBeerInteractor interactor, SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
    this.view= detailView;
    this.interactor = interactor;
    this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
}
```

In DetailActivity (called in onCreate):

```
@Override
protected void injectDependencies(BeerApp app) {
    app.getDetailSubComponent(this).inject(this);
}
```

and in the BeerApp:

```
public DetailSubComponent getDetailSubComponent(Activity activity) {
    if (detailSubComponent == null) {
        detailSubComponent = applicationComponent.plus(new DetailModule((DetailView) activity));
    }

    return detailSubComponent;
}
```

--- EDIT:

I removed the null validation and it worked too! but I do not know if this is correct:

```
public DetailSubComponent getDetailSubComponent(Activity activity) {
    detailSubComponent = applicationComponent.plus(new DetailModule((DetailView) activity));

    return detailSubComponent;
}
```

Comment: Try using some static data with Flowable.just in the load method. Furthermore, you need to dispose your subscriptions, when your intent is closed, due to possible memory leaks.

Comment: I was calling the dispose method on Activity's onPause, but I ended up taking it out on one of my tests. I'll put it back. I'm will do the test you suggested.

Comment: Show us where the detailPresenter is created. If You inject it using a framework or your own custom code, add that code to your question as well.

Comment: @Lukasz I found the problem. In fact it was a problem with dagger DI and not with RxJava. I was injecting the view in the presenter and that view stay attached. I solved it by creating a method to inject the view in constructor, instead doing it via dagger.

Comment: @alexpfx That's what I was suspecting. You can of course still provide the view via dagger. The way I would do this is create an activity scoped component providing the view and the presenter.

Comment: @Lukasz I update the question with the dagger part